# Packaging 2gp org

Tags: package, salesforce, command-line-interface, sfdx, salesforce-cli

I am currently encountered an issue while attempting to create a patch version in their 2GP package. While I have not been able to reproduce the issue myself as we need partner org to create patches, I am hoping that you may be able to provide some insight.

To provide some context, the customer was able to successfully create their first version from 0.1.0-1 to 0.1.1-1.

However, after making some changes such as adding new CustomObjects, deleting two Objects, and removing multiple custom fields from another object that were not needed in the package (utilizing pilot features to delete metadata from 2nd Gen package), they created a new Release (2.0.0-1) for these metadata, which also succeeded.

However, the customer has encountered an error when attempting to create any new patch to update the metadata from 2.0.0-1 to 2.0.1-1. This error is attached below. As a result, the customer has had to update their metadata by going from 2.0.0-1 to 2.1.0-1.

Any insights or guidance you may be able to provide regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.

We should be able to create patch after updating metadata.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQtBK.png)